# What does "Poor kids might come out quacking like a duck" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Let's imagine an amazing technology that could teach just about anything, but will it eliminate inequities in education?
>   Wealthy parents will get the best hardware for their own children, while the
>   children of poor households will have access to older models in need of repair. 
>   Rich kids will easily learn quantum physics. **Poor kids might come out quacking like a duck.**

In the above quote, what does "Poor kids might come out quacking like a duck" mean?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source and more of the context. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Might come out = might emerge (from a session where their brains were attached to the equipment) having been changed in such a way that....

Answer (score 1):

It means pretty much exactly what it sounds like: that the poor-quality devices that the poorer families could afford could have nasty side-effects from the general technology in use. These side effects could (hypothetically) be as bad as affecting their brains in such a way as to make them quack the way ducks do.

It's a bit of rhetorical hyperbole, but in principle it's not really impossible to rule that idea out for an invention that's acting on the mind so intricately.